# Модальное окно React в ответ на получение данных с сервера

Tags: reactjs, react-native, create-react-app, modal

Есть форма на React, которая отправляет дынные и получает ответ от сервера. На основании ответа нужно показывать модальное окно. Закрывать его кнопкой закрытия, и без перезагрузки страницы, при отправке данных повторно, показать новое модальное окно. Получается вызвать окно 1 раз, а потом состояние его открытия не меняется.

Это само модальное окно:

```
class ControlledPopupComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.state.locat = props.content[0];
        this.state.formView = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + props.content[1][0].view + ")"), null, 4);

        this.state.open = props.openView;

       // this.state.contetentModal = JSON.stringify(props.content[0]);


        console.log('data', props.content[2][0].open);
        console.log('form', JSON.stringify(eval("(" + props.content[1][0].view + ")"), null, 4)); 

        this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
        this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

        this.componentWillReceiveProps = this.componentWillReceiveProps.bind(this);

    }

    openModal() {
        this.setState({open: true, locat:this.props.content[0], formView: JSON.stringify(eval("(" + this.props.content[1][0].view + ")"), null, 4), contetentModal: JSON.stringify(this.props.content[0])  });
    }
    closeModal() {
        this.setState({ open: false });

    }

    handleChange() {
        this.setState({ open: true });

    }

    relocation(page) {
        this.setState({ page: page, open: false });
    }


    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
       console.log("nextProps", nextProps);
       console.log("nextState", nextState);
        console.log("data", nextProps.openView);
      // this.setState({open: true, locat:nextProps.content[0], formView: JSON.stringify(eval("(" + nextProps.content[1][0].view + ")"), null, 4), contetentModal: JSON.stringify(nextProps.content[0])  });
  //  this.state.locat = nextProps.content[0];
   //  this.state.formView = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + nextProps.content[1][0].view + ")"), null, 4);
  //    this.state.contetentModal = JSON.stringify(nextProps.content[0]);
 //     this.state.open = nextProps.content[2][0].open;


   return true;
 } 

    render() {
        return ( <
            div className = "modalView" >
            <
            Popup open = { this.state.open }
            closeOnDocumentClick  onClose = { this.closeModal } >
            <
            div className = "modal" >
            <`введите сюда код`
            a className = "close"
            onClick = { this.closeModal } >  &times;<
            /a> < /
            div > <div className="formView"><h2 className="title">Форма</h2><pre>{this.state.formView}</pre></div><
            Table loc = {this.state.locat }
            />< /Popup > < /div >
        );
    }
}

export default ControlledPopupComponent;
```

Рендериться оно в app.js, когда стейт там вот такой `controlledPopupComponent`

```
this.state.controlledPopupComponent
  ? <ControlledPopupComponent
  openView={this.state.open} 
  contetentModal={this.state.result}
  content={this.state.content} 
  model={this.state.model}
  inputs={this.state}
```

Данные приходят из формы, которая в компоненте форм

Comment: Добавьте код, который Вы описали в вопросе, чтобы можно было дать конкретный ответ на Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Да, проблема ясна и ее можно решить через `props` к примеру. Для начала нужно понять, кто будет управлять открытием и закрытием модального окна. Тут всё просто, на данный момент если в `controlledPopupComponent` что-то есть, то рендерится компонент `ControlledPopupComponent`. Однако управление отображением модалки находится внутри самого компонента `ControlledPopupComponent`, а не в компоненте, который его вызывает. Вот отсюда и проблема, в том, что отображается оно один раз. Решение следующее:

1. Перенести признак открытия модального окна `open` - в родительский компонент, а из компонента `ControlledPopupComponent` убрать его из `state` и брать из `props`.
2. Написать метод, в родительском компоненте, который просто меняет знаяние переменной `open` - простой метод с одной строкой кода.
3. Передать метод смены значения `open` в компонент `ControlledPopupComponent` и вызывать его при закрытии модального окна.

В грубом примере код будет выглядеть так (родительский компонент):

```
onChangeModalState = () => {
  this.setState({ isOpen: this.state.isOpen });
}
```

Код просто меняет значение переменной `isOpen` с `true` на `false` и обратно. Метод простой, его даже не нужно байндить в конструкторе, так как используется стрелочная функция и `this` уже будет проброшен. (Либо можно написать два метода - `onClose` и `onOpen` вместо одного, чтобы не было путаницы в дальнейшем)

Далее передача метода и состояния открытости/закрытости в дочерний компонент (заменил `openView` на `isOpen`, почему-то складывается ощущение, что это то же самое было у Вас):

```
<ControlledPopupComponent
  isOpen={this.state.isOpen} 
  onChangeModalState={this.onChangeModalState}
  contetentModal={this.state.result}
  content={this.state.content} 
  model={this.state.model}
  inputs={this.state}
/>
```

Тут две очевидных пропсы - это `isOpen`, где лежит признак открыто окно или нет, и `onChangeModalState` - метод, который меняет этот призак. Теперь перейдем к дочернему компоненту.

1. Убрать метод `closeModal` - теперь этим занимается родительский компонент (и привязку `bind` из конструктора).
2. Убрать метод `handleChange` - он вообще не используется (и привязку `bind` из конструктора).
3. В конструкторе `this.state.open = props.openView;` - это плохой код. Никогда не меняйте состояние через присваивание, всегда используйте метод `setState`, а для конструткора вообще пишут конструкции следующего вида: `this.state = { open: props.openView }`. Это для примера, эту строку тоже удаляем. Оставляйте в стейте `locat` и `formView` (`this.state = { locat: 'ваше значение', formView: 'ваше значение' }`), остальное вроде бы уже не понадобится.
4. Метод `relocation` не привязан, а Вы в нем пытаетесь менять `state` - не сработает, но это просто к общему замечанию. Чтобы он работал нормально - либо прибайндить в конструкторе, либо использовать стрелочную функцию.
5. Далее метод рендеринга - `render`. Там заменяем `open={this.state.open}` на `open={this.props.isOpen}`, `onClose={this.closeModal}` на `onClose={this.props.onChangeModalState}`, `onClick={this.closeModal}` на `onClick={this.props.onChangeModalState}`.

После этого, код должен начать работать более предсказуемо. Управлением отображения модалки занимается родитель, а не сам компонент. Компоненту не нужно управлять собой, ему нужно знать, когда появиться и всё.

Comment: Проблема в том, что окно должно открываться, по клику на кнопку отправки данных, данные с сервера приходят и нужно отобразить их в окне, я закрываю окно, и без перезагрузки страницы ввожу новую форму, данные приходят, но окно не открывает, как-будто больше не идет к этому компоненту.

Comment: @Totoro Вы переписали код в соответсвии с моим ответом? Когда данные снова приходят - нужно вызвать метод `onChangeModalState` чтобы поменялся признак с `false` на  `true`, и тогда модалка откроется снова. Причем, по-хорошему, признаком открытия окна должна быть не `this.state.controlledPopupComponent`, а `this.state.isOpen`